# Dataflow Vs. BQ CLI : Which one is more efficient in terms of performance and costing

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have some requirements which can be handled using both Dataflow as well as BQ CLI. I have done some performance analysis on both and found that handling `Transformations` through various operations on `PCollections` brings some significant delays when compared against running the queries on BQ CLI for same transformation operations.

My requirement includes the transformations which can be handled using SQL queries having lots of `Joins`and I was wondering to write the equivalent Dataflow logics for the same.

As per my analysis, if there are complex transformations to build then using `BQ CLI` would always facilitate a better performance if compared against handling the same over `PCollections` using Java equivalent logics.

Please suggest whether I can have any performance and cost related benefits if I implement the stuffs in Dataflow rather than writing SQL queries to be run in BQ CLI.

Comment: Dataflow ingests data into BigQuery by using exactly the same public BigQuery REST APIs that BigQuery CLI does - however, BigQuery CLI does not (and can not) do anything else, so naturally, CLI is equally or more efficient but less flexible.

Comment: @jkff So basically both Dataflow and Bigquery uses the exactly same methology for `Data Injection`. Then the only point where Dataflow may be less efficient is handling various `Transformations` over the data. If I handle the transformations using SQL queries running on BigQuery CLI, then by using BigQuery REST API, it may provide faster performance when compared against handling the same transformations in Dataflow by writing the equivalent Java logic.

Comment: Sounds right. Especially for small amounts of data, where the dataflow job will be dominated by cost of startup and shutdown of vms.

Comment: Thank you @jkff. Apparently it can be concluded that in case any transformation can be handled in both ways (Dataflow jobs and Bigquery as well), then going ahead with Bigquery would be a wise approach for gaining a better performance matrix. (If volume of data is not way too high)

Comment: Yeah. AFAIK at high scale a well-optimized Dataflow job can outperform BigQuery, however if you can accomplish something in a single SQL query in BigQuery, it's better to just do that - if anything, it'll be less coding.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Your valuable inputs will definitely help me deciding the selection of right tool/techniques at right time.